# Meaning of the statement - test -x /usr/bin/find || exit 0

Tags: shell, test

I just wanted to understand the meaning of the following statement and whether they seem correct.

```
test -x /usr/bin/find || exit 0 
Command 1
Command 2
Command 3
```

The output of `test -x /usr/bin/find` is always 0. That means the exit 0 command will be executed , meaning Command 1, 2, 3 will never be executed. Am I right here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`test -x /usr/bin/find` (or `[ -x /usr/bin/find ]`) does not output anything.  The test will be *true* if `/usr/bin/find` is an existing executable file, and *false* if the pathname does not exist, or if it's not executable.

If `test` exits successfully (with a zero exits status, signifying "no error"), the shell will execute the rest of the commands.  If it exits with a failure (a non-zero exit status, signifying "some error"), `exit 0` will terminate the current shell, preventing the rest of the commands from running.

It would arguably be better to use `exit 1` or just `exit` in place of `exit 0` when `find` can't be found in `/usr/bin` though.  Using `exit 0` masks the exit status of `test` (which would be non-zero), and prevents the caller of this script from being notified of the failure of finding `find` at the given location.

Related to the fact that an exit status of zero evaluates to  "true" when tested as a boolean in the shell:

- [Why the Unix command exit with non-zero value in Shell and evaluates to True when used in bash if condition?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/683438)

Related to using `||` and `&&` in general:

- [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513)

Answer (score 4):

No, they will always be executed. In `man bash` it says (it works like that in each POSIX shell):

```
   An OR list has the form

          command1 || command2

   command2  is executed if, and only if, command1 returns a non-zero exit
   status.
```

Since `test -x /usr/bin/find` returns 0 command2 (`exit 0` in this
case) is not executed and script continues execution.

Comment: Can you add a similar description for AND also?

Comment: How would a command like (a && b) || c will get executed?

Comment: @DawsonSmith it is exactly the same: your confusion stems from the fact that in the shell, a `0` exit status means success and not failure as is the case in many other contexts.